# While appending text to a file, lsof doesn't show the file as being open / accessed

Tags: rhel, lsof

On one session I append some text to a file as below :

```
while true;do echo some_text >> file1 ; done
```

On another session from same dir I run :

```
lsof file1
```

which returns no output. Any idea why ? Shouldn't lsof report the process writing to the file ?
I'm on RHEL 7.2

Comment: When you do `echo some_text >> file1` the file is open for a couple of milliseconds, so you would need to launch lsof at exactly the right time...

Comment: @xenoid I thought about that when I had a `sleep` inside my loop for each iteration. But then I removed it and as you see it's an infinite loop without sleep. Is it still the case in this infinite loop ? During the loop I tried **many many times** the lsof but I continuously get no output at all. I don't think I am that unlucky

Comment: @nullPointer sorry, didn't notice it. But you really are that unlucky: run the `lsof` in a loop too: `while true; do lsof file1; done`, and it will certainly pick some of intervals when `file1` is open. And btw, use `true >> file1` instead of `echo >> file1` if you don't want to fill your disk with junk.

Comment: @mosvy It did pick up indeed.. many thanks.. just a side question, would this be the same case if the file is being FTP-ed from another machine ? Would it be open intermittently, hence lsof would only report it at irregular intervals ? Or it would be open continuously meaning lsof would continuously report it ?

Comment: During an FTP file transfer the file would be continuously open, however nothing says it is open under the final name, it could be open using a temp name with a final rename at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just "bad luck" (or if you prefer, a very narrow time window). You can slow the process with `pv` to throttle the writes to lengthen the time during which the file is open:

```
echo "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" | pv -L 2 >> opened.dat
```

and in another terminal:

```
lsof opened.dat 
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
pv      30636   me    1w   REG  253,1       60 24642407 opened.dat
```